# yii2 stripe include error (class not found)

Tags: yii2, stripe-payments

Yii2 Framework.
Installed Stripe (https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php) by composer:

```
composer require stripe/stripe-php
```

And inserted to the view:

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_...');
$myCard = array(
    'number' => '4242424242424242',
    'exp_month' => 8,
    'exp_year' => 2018
);
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
    'card' => $myCard,
    'amount' => 2000,
    'currency' => 'usd'
));
echo $charge;
```

And now framework can't find Class:

```
Error

Class 'Stripe\Stripe' not found
```

What should I do next?

Comment: Yup, error is the same

Comment: Please give the path of that extension in your view in header,just type stripe so that you will get path of that extension.

Answer (score 0):

Did you correctly include Composer's autoload file?

You should have a `require` statement similar to this near the beginning of your code:

```
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
```

cf. Stripe's PHP library's [README file](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php#composer) and [Composer's documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading).

Comment: Yii2 framework includes autoload.php file automatically. But even after inserting that code it made no sense. Still the same error.